how to open Call setting screen from android app programmatically
I am trying to navigate from my app to device's Call setting screen and voicemail setting screen.
I am looking for Action to create intent that can navigate to setting screen.
or other way to open Call Setting Screen of Device and Voicemail Setting Screen

  try {
       val callIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
       callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:$s"))
       startActivity(callIntent)
      } catch (activityException: ActivityNotFoundException) {
        Log.d("Calling a Phone Number", "Call failed$activityException")
     }

     This is code for open Device Dial screen with intent.

